# asp.net proxy server denied to access included javascript files in my website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, proxy

I am facing strange problem that my website opens but proxy server denied to access to included java script files (**j query... etc**) in website , returns me in chrome console proxy **error 502** i guess .

some of included files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.wheelmenu.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/color.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery-1.11.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/multipleAccordion.js"></script>
```

all i want to know can i resolve this problem from my side , or i should to ask network administrator for this problem .

note : outside the office website works very well .

please advice :(

Comment: If you put or append(afer http://localhost:9292/) assets/js/jquery.wheelmenu.min.js in URL. Is it able to show content?

Comment: no , i got proxy server message network access 502 ....etc @amit

Comment: Then that's your issue. Check directory relative path is correct and it has permission.